# Problems with factorial function in Python (see codes)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, function, numpy

I made a factorial function using numpy. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np

def factorial(x):
    n=[]
    if x==1:
        return 1
    if x>1:
        while x>1:
            x-=1
            n.append(x+1)
    return np.prod(np.array(n))
```

That function does work well until factorial(12).

On the other hand, this one works with any number:

```
def fact(n):
    num = 1
    while n > 1:
        num *= n
        n -= 1
    return num
```

This get worse when for example I try to calculate 20!:

```
factorial(20)
Out[65]: -2102132736            #Wrong

fact(20)
Out[66]: 2432902008176640000    #Correct
```

Does anybody could help me to understand what's wrong with my function? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: return np.prod(np.array(n, dtype="float32")) or some type with big range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the numpy library which uses C-style fixed-precision integers, they can overflow. This is what's happening in your factorial function. To fix this, you must construct an array of dtype 'int64' for larger factorials.

I'd like to add that this doesn't occur in normal Python integers as the language automatically converts them to long integers before they overflow.

Comment: I'd like to know why this was downvoted. If I'm wrong, by all means, correct me.